# Building task list with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, list, task

I have basic knowledge in PHP and MySQL.

Im trying to build an application for employees working with a weekly task list. I have a working application for other duties with user login etc. so I need this "task list application" to be integrated.

I have an idea how to do this in a bad way, so I need your help to be "pushed into right direction" =)

Every task list is stored for statistics etc.

Right know my table kind of looks like this (real table contains 50+ tasks):

```
ID || userID || task1 || task1description || task2 || task2description || timestamp
```

Right now I have set "Standard value" in the description fields, for describing the task. The reason for this is that I want to echo the full task list in a while loop.

I suppose there is a much better way to do this? Above solution works but my table gets very large because every row contains the descriptions. Another solution is to manually write descriptions in HTML, but I want everything to be dynamic.

Plz help! =)

Comment: Easy. See normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have multiple tables and use foreign keys. You should *normalize* your database.

For instance have a table `users` that contains a `user_id`, `username`, pherhaps `password` etc.

and have a separate table that `tasks` which has columns `task_id`, `task_name`, and `task_description`

Then have a table to link them together `user_tasks` which has just two columns `user_id` and `task_id`

This way you can assign users (more than one if you need) to tasks

Use *foreign keys* in your `user_tasks` table to ensure that that only valid `user_id`s and `task_id`s are used on your `user_task` table

example tables:
Users:

```
 user_id || user_name || password
 12       || jim       || Il0vecATS
 13       || jane      || jimsuzx
```

Tasks:

```
task_id || task_name || task_descr
1       || clean up  || sweep the kitchen
```

User Tasks:

```
user_id    || task_id
12         || 1
```

Jim is in charge of sweeping the kitchen